# Find coordinate of point on the boundary of a circle given a latitude/longitude and radius

Tags: distance, spherical-geometry

I understand how to use the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to compute the distance between two points on the earth. However, I would like to answer a similar, albeit different question. How can I compute the latitude/longitude of any point on the boundary of a circle?

For instance, I have a center point at 31.782643, -102.291938 and a radius of 245km. I would like to find the latitude/longitude coordinate for any point on the edge of this circle. How can I do this?

Comment: This is known as the Geodetic Forward Problem.  Both it and the Geodetic Inverse Problem (of which haversine is an approximation, since it does not calculate on a spheroid) are solved by FORTRAN code from the US Geodetic Survey http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/Inv_Fwd/